# CKFinder: Custom sorting of files

Tags: javascript, ckfinder

I have written a custom CKFinder backend for an abstract filesystem (not dissimilar to the [sample Database Storage Plugin](https://github.com/ckfinder/ckfinder-plugin-database-adapter-php/)). In addition to the basic file info, it also sends back a few extra bits of data to the GetFiles command, including an "order" field which indicates the order in which the files should be displayed.

This is an example response to `?command=GetFiles` (prettified):

```
{  
   "resourceType":"Files",
   "currentFolder":{  
      "path":"\/",
      "acl":17,
      "url":"\/"
   },
   "files":[  
      {  
         "name":"File 1",
         "date":"19700101010000",
         "size":0,
         "order":"2",
      },
      {  
         "name":"File 2",
         "date":"19700101010000",
         "size":0,
         "order":"3",
      },
      {  
         "name":"File 3",
         "date":"19700101010000",
         "size":0,
         "order":"1",
      },
   ]
}
```

When the files are rendered by CKFinder, I would like them to be sorted according to the "order" value.

This should only occur for the custom backend that outputs the "order" value - other backends should just sort them as normal.

I can't find the right combination of events/requests to achieve this using a plugin on the JavaScript side, and can't see any way to influence the order of files from the backend side. Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: From what I'm aware command modification is one thing but CKFinder UI uses its own sorting methods (settings in right-hand panel) which are applied by default and have no option to be overwritten or extended. It doesn’t really look (at least to me) that it is possible to implement your own file sorting.

Comment: @j.swiderski Thanks for letting me know. What's the best way to submit a feature request?

Comment: You can report a feature here: https://github.com/ckfinder/ckfinder/issues